# why this c++ code gives such output?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string str ;
string STR ;

int main(){

    for(int I=0;I<6;I++)    /// 012345
        str[I] = I + '0'  ;

    for(int J=0;J<6;J++)    /// abcdef
        STR[J] = J + 'a' ;

    cout << str << "  " << STR << endl ; /// blank line !!!


    printf("%s\n",str.c_str()); /// abcdef
    printf("%s\n",STR.c_str()); /// abcdef

    return 0;
}
```

output ::

```
abcdef
abcdef
```

I expect ::

```
012345 abcdef
012345
abcdef
```

Answer (score 7):

You have *undefined behavior*!

The strings you declare are *empty*, and indexing of them will be out of bounds.

Instead you should *append* the characters to the string, either using the [`append`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) member function or the [`+=` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D).

Comment: ohhh ... ,man,tnx ... instead of doing "str += I + '0' ;"  I was doing " str[I] += I + '0'  ; " ...now it works ....